# Symfony2 check if user has access to url inside Twig

Tags: php, symfony, security, twig

Is there a way in Symfony2 to check if user has access to specified url inside Twig template?

Something like this:

```
{% if user_has_access( '/some/url/to/access' ) %}
   <a href="{{ path( '/some/url/to/access' ) }}">You can come here</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Paweł Brzoski explained, it's possible to create a custom twig function.

But in Symfony, the correct way is to use `is_granted('ROLE_...')`

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just not out-of-the-box. [I did this in Airship](https://github.com/paragonie/airship/blob/master/src/Cabin/Bridge/Lens/cargo/bridge_menu.twig): `{% if can('read', 'url/endpoint') %}` or more generally, `{% if can_read('url/endpoint') %}`

Comment: There question was "in Symfony2". There is nothing out of the box to do this, but sure you can code it... Airship is not a Symfony2 project so it's not really in the context.

Comment: Airship uses Twig. Symfony2 uses Twig. Yes, it is possible to do this in Symfony2. What I provided was a counterexample to your false statement of "It's not possible".

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. `is_granted` checks for specific roles, and this does not check whether a user can acccess a specific URL

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can create custom Twig extension for that.

More information about extension you can find in documentation.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Fox example:
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

```
class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('user_has_access', array($this, 'userHasAccess')),
        );
    }

    public function userHasAccess($user, $pathForCheck)
    {
        //your logic for check access. can returns true or false
        return true;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

and in twig template

```
{% if user_has_access(app.user, 'path/to/check') %}
{% endif %}
```

This code can have error, because it's only prototype.

Comment: You want a function here, not a filter.

Comment: This filter works great.  Here is how I used it in Twig:
`{% if item.url|user_has_access %}
{% endif %}`
Note that you don't need to pass `app.user`, because you can obtain it with `\Drupal::currentUser()` in the AppExtension class.

Comment: Can you share more information? I think the most important part is missing: the logic within that filter, function, however you call ist. How does this look like?